# How to get all meshs added in with a import script?

Tags: python, scripting, import, parent

Right now I am making a import script for my file format. I have the model appearing fine and doing everything I need except I need to get all the meshes created and add them under an empty object I created also.

Here is what I have now: https://paste.ofcode.org/AsYmmmV6tTdcR79UJrTy5X

Now on line 95 you will see I create an empty object. My question is how can I get all the meshes created using the add_mesh_to_scene. So basically any mesh added to the scene will be parented under that empty object. I have went through and tried other peoples answer about parenting but cant find a way to do this no matter what I try. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well looks like I found my own answer. @batFINGER answered it correctly but in my situation with so many functions I couldnt pass all them variables through each one. So I decided to do a for loop and check for the objects name that was the one I wanted all other objects to be parented, then added that object to a variable named parent, like this:

```
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
        if ob.name == "Empty":
            parent = ob
```

After that to set all objects that were not named that as a child of the parent variable like so:

```
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
        if ob.name != "Empty":
            ob.parent = parent
```

So yeah with some experimentation I did it. Thanks @batFINGER for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

**Add an empty object and set as parent**

Rather than edit into your code I have added an example of how to add objects and set to have same parent.  Have used "dummy" version of your `add_mesh_to_scene` to illustrate.

Uses the default cube mesh as a proxy for the imported mesh.  Adds an empty at the cursor location and `num_objects = 4` as the children of that empty.  Set the inverse parent matrix to position the imported mesh objects where they would be without an empty parent at cursor location.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

num_objects = 4
def create_mesh():
    # dummy method returns def cube mesh
    return bpy.data.meshes.get("Cube")

def add_mesh_to_scene(scene, mesh):
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(mesh.name, mesh)
    scene.objects.link(obj)
    return obj

if num_objects:
    # code to add empty parent
    mt = bpy.data.objects.new("Handle", None)
    scene.objects.link(mt)
    mw = Matrix.Translation(scene.cursor_location)
    mt.matrix_world = mw
    # return as active
    scene.objects.active = mt
    mwi = mw.inverted()

    for i in range(num_objects):
        me = create_mesh()
        ob = add_mesh_to_scene(scene, me)
        ob.parent = mt
        # setting this keeps them in import locs.
        ob.matrix_parent_inverse = mwi
        # set some loc to visualize
        ob.location.x += 1.1 * i * ob.dimensions.x
        # return as selected
        ob.select = True
    # update scene once.    
    scene.update()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still cant seem to figure out how to add it in my code. It seems I am always getting some error. Also I dont know how exactly I am gonna get all objects I have added. For example you variable num_objects. Basically I need a way to add all objects I create in a list or array and then do a for and add them to the parent obj I create. Thanks for helping me!